# Thymeleaf - check if a template exists

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am searching a way to check if a template exists before returning it in a view with Thymeleaf and Spring.

In my controller i was trying to do something like this:

```
String finalTemplate = template.getPrefix() + "/" + templateName;

        try {
            return finalTemplate;
        } catch(TemplateInputException e) {
            logger.debug("Sono qua");
            return templateName;
        }
```

but the exception is not catch...

Comment: finally have figured it out,     
 `ITemplateResource iTemplateResource = new StringTemplateResource("pages/print-orders/items/custom/" + productCategoryUuid + "-print-order-item-form");
if(iTemplateResource.exists()) {
}`

Comment: Oh, thanks! I will try it as soon as i can!

Comment: @Amare, return true if is a html template and is a folder, but not if is a valid template file only.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are handling exception here will not work for template exceptions.

Check below threads regarding this in issues section github.

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/94

https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/81

Comment: did you able to resolve this issue? I have a scenario where if a template exists then it loads that template if not faillbacks to a default template

Answer (score 1):

`StringTemplateResource` from the comment above seems to return true in every case for thymeleaf 3.0. Here is a method to do this for classpath included templates:

```java
  public static String baseDir = "templates";

  /**
   * Check if a template exists in subfolder templates.
   *
   * @param templateName relative name of template below the basedir.
   * @return true if exists, otherwise false
   */
  public static boolean templateExists(final String templateName)
  {
    final ClassLoaderTemplateResource iTemplateResource =
        new ClassLoaderTemplateResource(baseDir + "/" + templateName, "UTF8");
    return iTemplateResource.exists();
  }
```

Testcase:

```java
  @Test
  public void testNonExisting()
  {
    assertFalse(templateExists("foo"));
  }

  @Test
  public void testExisting()
  {
    assertTrue(templateExists("foo.txt"));
  }
```

Assuming a classpath resource `templates/foo.txt` exists.