# Thymeleaf specify failback template

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

My application needs to send different emails based on dynamic parameter. The email templates are stored in classpath resource with structure:

```
company1/html/NEW_DOCUMENT_TPL/template
company2/html/NEW_DOCUMENT_TPL/template
```

Depending on this dynamic parameter i am trying to load template I want. This is working just fine. Now I want to in case of template does not exist to use default template with path:
`html/NEW_DOCUMENT_TPL/template`
I managed to do this with try/catch clause:

```
try {
            templateBody = emailTemplateEngine.process(getTemplateUrl(templateParams), context);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            templateBody = emailTemplateEngine.process(getTemplateUrlWithoutRealm(templateParams), context);
        }
```

The problem with this solution is that there is nasty exception printed in logs:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [company1/html/NEW_DOCUMENT_TPL/template], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

In thymeleaf TemplateManager i see that there is a property failIfNotExists which would work perfectly

```
    if (!failIfNotExists) {
                // In this case we will not consider that a "not exists" means a failure. Maybe we are in a scenario
                // (e.g. some types of operations with FragmentExpressions) in which we desire this.
                return null;
            }
    
    throw new TemplateInputException(
      "Error resolving template [" + template + "], " +
      "template might not exist or might not be accessible by " +
      "any of the configured Template Resolvers");
```

but it seems this is used to handle totally different use case and I cant find a way to set this property.

So my question is: **how to set failback template/how to check if template exists**?

Using thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE. I already tried solution provided here: [Thymeleaf - check if a template exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139371/thymeleaf-check-if-a-template-exists) without success (template manager finds the template correctly but this method indicates that template does not exist.